# Dimension of an array when returning from a function

Tags: c

I can not understand the difference in array size of this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*foo(void))[3] {
    static int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    printf("Dimension inside = %d\n", sizeof(array));
    return array;
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    printf("Dimension outside = %d\n", sizeof(foo()));
    return 0;
}
```

In particular the first `foo()` printa one size (`12`) while the second call of `foo()` inside `sizeof()` give me just `4`.

Moreover, what is the purpose the declare that the function return a pointer of an array of 3 int? A thing like `int *foo(void)` would be the same. Right?

Comment: return value decays as a pointer

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Each `int` is 4 bytes. An array of 3 `ints` is thus 12 bytes. A pointer in a 32-bit process is 4 bytes.

Comment: h0r53: yes, that's was clear. I did not remember the array inside the function, when returning, decays in a pointer.

Comment: `foo` is a function returning pointer to array 3 of int. In C++: `int(*foo(void))[3]; static_assert(sizeof(foo()) == sizeof(void *)); static_assert(sizeof(*foo()) == sizeof(int) * 3);`

Comment: The point is, it does not return an array, it returns a pointer to an array. The issue is not even about decay (although also you cannot return an array directly)

Comment: Artefacto: Interesting. Thank you

Comment: Sorry but If the function in any case return just a pointer to an array, what is the purpose the declare that the function return a pointer of an array of 3 int? A thing like int *foo(void) would be the same. Right?

Comment: @user5507798 you can do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/GzKPb4 . If you change the type of `v` to `int (*)[4]`, you'll see a compiler warning (incompatible pointer type). So the size of array is preserved as long as it's behind a pointer. In practice, people don't do this and return directly the decayed array. That avoids the extra indirection, even though the extra indirection allows preserving the array type (avoids the decay).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this question is not a duplicate of the other you identified. See my comments here.

Comment: @user5507798 `int *foo(void)` wouldn't be the same. You have one less level of indirection. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/MseY8q) you return the array decayed into a pointer. Consequently, you get the third element with `v[2]`, not `(*v)[2]`.

Comment: can you suggest another duplicate then? @Artefacto

Answer (score 1):

This `&` returns pointer to array and not to the first int:

```
return &array;
```

Same value, different type.

With `*foo()` foo's return value can be dereferenced and have it's size taken:

```
sizeof(*foo());
```

I get size 12 inside and outside, and no warnings.

Whereas `foo()` and `&foo` have 8 as size.

`*foo()` means `*(foo())` but the parens can be left away.

**Purpose?**

To return a pointer to a static array is already questionable - why not declare the array itself outside the function?

Then it depends what you really want. `-Wall` indicates this basic problem:

```
warning: returning 'int *' from a function with
         incompatible return type 'int (*)[3]'
```

--> Foo() is inconsistent in itself.

As a simple `int *foo()` you can use `foo()` like a 3-int array:

```
printf("%d\n", foo()[1] );   // prints "2"
```

With a second dimension (`return &array`) it becomes:

```
printf("%d\n", foo()[0][1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior for multiple reasons:

- `printf("Dimension inside = %d\n", sizeof(array));` passes a `size_t` when `printf` expects an `int` value for `%d`: use `%zu` instead.
- `return array;` is a type mismatch: you define the function as returning a pointer to an array of 3 `int`. Return `&array` to fix this.
- `printf("Dimension outside = %d\n", sizeof(foo()));` has the same conversion problem, and you print the size of a pointer instead of that of the object pointed to which is why you get different sizes. Use this instead:

  ```
  printf("Dimension outside = %zu\n", sizeof(*foo()));
  ```
- also note that there is no *second call* to `foo()`: `sizeof(foo())` does not evaluate its argument, it simply evaluates to the size of the return type of `foo()` at compile time, but does not generate a function call.
- `int *foo(void)` would mean something different: it would define `foo()` as returning a pointer to `int`, which by the way would be consistent with returning `array`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*foo(void))[3] {
    static int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    printf("Dimension inside = %zu\n", sizeof(array));
    return &array;
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    printf("Dimension outside = %zu\n", sizeof(*foo()));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Dimension inside = 12
Dimension outside = 12
```

This explanation aside, it is not idiomatic for a function to return a pointer to an array and many a C programmer will mentally parse the function definition incorrectly and miss the subtlety of this approach.